# How to make a main section scroll while left, right menu's and navbar stay still?

Tags: html, css

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>The testing page</title>

        <style type="text/css">
        body{

            margin: 0px;
            padding: 0px;

        }

        #topbar{

            background-color: blue;
            width: 100%;
            height: 35px;
            margin: 0px auto; 


        }

        #logo{

            width: 100px;
            margin-left: 100px; 
            float: left;


        }

        #searchbar{

            margin-top: 5px;
            margin-left: 10px;
            height: 25px;
            width: 400px;
            float: left;
            border-radius: 2px;
            border: 1px #000 solid;
            padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 5;

        }

        #leftmenu{

            float: left;
            width: 300px;
            background-color: green;
            height: 500px;
            margin-left: 25px;
            margin-top: 10px;

        }

        #main{

            background-color: yellowgreen;
            height: 100%;
            width: 500px;
            position: relative;
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-left: 335px;
            padding: 16px;

        }

        h1{
            margin: 0px

        }

        p{
            margin: 0px

        }



        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="topbar">

            <img id="logo" src="images/explogo.png">
            <input id="searchbar" type="text" placeholder="Search">

        </div>

        <div id="leftmenu">
        </div>

        <div id="main">
                <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
                <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
                <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <p>Some text some text some text some text..</p>
                <h1>Fixed Top Menu</h1>
                <h2>Scroll this page to see the effect</h2>
                <h2>The navigation bar will stay at the top of the page while scrolling</h2>

        </div>





    </body>

</html>
```

Ive been learning CSS and HTML but i'm a total newbie, i know some of you are going to laugh. But, how do i make the main section scroll while the left, right menu's and navigation bar stay still? I've added some text in the main section, but when i scroll the left menu, navbar and main scroll together

Answer (score 0):

If you change your #main to the below a scroll bar will appear. Is that what you're going for? The changes are making your height a static value and then adding a scrolling overflow. I had to adjust the width as well for your particular example.

```
 #main{
        background-color: yellowgreen;
        width: 450px;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-left: 335px;
        padding: 16px;
        height:500px;
        overflow:scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, thats similar to what i wanted. Except i want the main to scroll past the the navbar just like in Facebook, any ideas?

Comment: Its ok, i figured it out